# Textarea ng-model keeps last value even after an update from controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

This is a fairly simplified but I guess the representative view of the problem. Be aware that I have limited knowledge in Angular in particular.

I have a form with a `<pre>` block that displays a non-editable JSON string (StringA) and then a button that enables the view of a textarea in which I can edit the JSON-formatted string (StringB) and submit it to the backend. The problem is that even if I update StringA by other means (i.e. not through the browser editor) and retrieve it to the frontend to display it, the string in the textarea that is supposed to be binded to StringB by `ng-nmodel=StringB` is never updated, it keeps the last value, that I lastly edited in the textarea. It is important to say that whenever I enable de edit mode, StringB gets updated in by angular code by `StringB = JSON.stringify(StringA, null, '  ')`. I even print the value to the console of both StringA and StringB and I can see they have the proper values (basically both are the same) but the string I see in textarea is always the string I last edited by browser means.

For example, say StringA is `"{"A": 1}"` and I enable edit mode and then I format that string and assign to StringB so it gets properly displayed in the textarea. So I modify it to `{"A": 2}` and submit to the backend. Now I modify several times StringA (by a REST API) and retrieve to the frontend to display it in non-edit mode. Now StringA has value `{"A": 5}` and I enable edit mode. Textarea will still display `{"A": 2}` which was the last value I edited by browser means even if as seen in `configEdit` function, I have modified the value of StringB.

Here HTML code:

```
<div class="form">

    <div ng-hide="showEditor" ng-model="StringA">
        <pre>{{StringA | json}}</pre>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="showEditor">
        <textarea id="editArea" ng-model="StringB" 
        ng-show="showEditor">
        </textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="button" type="submit" 
    ng-click="configEdit()" ng-hide="showEditor"> Edit </button>

    <button class="button" type="submit" 
    ng-click="update(StringB)" ng-show="showEditor"> Submit </button>

</div>
```

I will also include the JS code although I can imagine the problem comes from not correctly handling the frontend (maybe I should not use a textarea, etc.)

```
$scope.configEdit= function() {
    $scope.showEditor= true;
    $scope.StringB= JSON.stringify($scope.StringA, null, '  ');
};
```

Comment: Try using ng-bind instead of ng-model for stringA on div element...

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your problem.....?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's issue in your code...
In your js code you are using `stringA` where as in html `StringA`. use proper coding standards to avoid such issues

And you should not have ng-model on div

Comment: Sorry it was a misspelled variable.

Comment: ohh in that case create js fiddle with the issue so that we can help u...

Comment: Yes I will try now